# https connections with android failing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, https, xamarin.android

I'm using a self signed cert and trying to connect to a local server via https. Here's my code:

In PCL:

```
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler(false, true) { ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual, }, false))
    {

        text = await client.GetStringAsync(address);
    }
```

android:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
            (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => certificate.GetCertHashString() == "abc123";
```

The callback is never called. When a do a GET with the client, it throws an exception which is null and gives me no info. This shows in the log which is normal i think:

12-08 08:40:43.175 D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 5796): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

I'm deploying the app on my google pixel xl with nougat. I tried with a version 6.0 emulator, no luck. i get this:

12-08 08:50:42.137 D/ ( 1428): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x99f44ac0, tid 1457
12-08 08:50:42.149 I/OpenGLRenderer( 1428): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-08 08:50:42.199 W/EGL_emulation( 1428): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-08 08:50:42.199 W/OpenGLRenderer( 1428): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9b868b60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-08 08:50:42.557 D/Mono ( 1428): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').

Both devices crash at the same place at GET.
The above code works fine on my wpf client. Does android have some special flags I need to set?

log files: http://pastebin.com/r3sAvkn6
           http://pastebin.com/3GPf7Dqc

Comment: Can you provide URI you are trying to connect to?

Comment: its an internal ip address to a machine I have. I can assure that the server is ok because i can connect with wpf and fiddler in the exact same manner.

Comment: When I use your code I get connection reset

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object ob, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
            {
                return true;
            };

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
            {
                var tt = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                string tx = await tt.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //Log.Info(TAG, tx);
            }
```

Comment: no luck. same thing happens. some exception occurs but its null. its probably an error xamarin internally.

Comment: If you provide sample solution to reproduce I might help more... But it probably depends on your server too

Answer (score 0):

Problem was NativeMessageHandler. Somehow it started working when I switched back to HttpClientHandler.

Comment: Have you tried NativeMessageHandler without parameters as I suggested?